# How to put two of the same divs in 2 by 2 column for download options

Tags: html, css

I want to know if you can make a way to make my download options in a 2 by 2 column? I saw one and it looked very rad and I was wondering if I could try to make but I'm getting stuck on the centering in the middle of the screen and making it a 2 by 2.    ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍      ‍

```css
.download {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="download">
  <h1>
    This Is The Title 1
  </h1>
  <p>
    Desc 1
  </p>
  <p>
    Realeased */*/*
  </p>
  <br>
    <a class="button" href="#">Download</a>
</div><div class="download">
  <h1>
    This Is The Title 2
  </h1>
  <p>
    Desc 2
  </p>
  <p>
    Realeased */*/*
  </p>
  <br>
    <a class="button" href="#">Download</a>
</div>
<div class="download">
  <h1>
    This Is The Title 3
  </h1>
  <p>
    Desc 3
  </p>
  <p>
    Realeased */*/*
  </p>
  <br>
    <a class="button" href="#">Download</a>
</div>
<div class="download">
  <h1>
    This Is The Title 4
  </h1>
  <p>
    Desc 4
  </p>
  <p>
    Realeased */*/*
  </p>
  <br>
    <a class="button" href="#">Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i answered your question, if it helps please accept and up-vote

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the same `divs` in a `container` then you can center the container by using following `CSS`. Also the `width+padding` of each `div` is `212px` and you want to put 2 `divs` in each row so `width+padding` of `container` should be `424px`. Same for the `height+padding`.

```css
.download {
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
  }
  
  .button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  .container{
      
    width: 424px;
    height: 540;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="divs_in_cols.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="download">
            <h1>
                This Is The Title 1
            </h1>
            <p>
                Desc 1
            </p>
            <p>
                Realeased */*/*
            </p>
            <br>
            <a class="button" href="#">Download</a>
        </div>
        <div class="download">
            <h1>
                This Is The Title 2
            </h1>
            <p>
                Desc 2
            </p>
            <p>
                Realeased */*/*
            </p>
            <br>
            <a class="button" href="#">Download</a>
        </div>
        <div class="download">
            <h1>
                This Is The Title 3
            </h1>
            <p>
                Desc 3
            </p>
            <p>
                Realeased */*/*
            </p>
            <br>
            <a class="button" href="#">Download</a>
        </div>
        <div class="download">
            <h1>
                This Is The Title 4
            </h1>
            <p>
                Desc 4
            </p>
            <p>
                Realeased */*/*
            </p>
            <br>
            <a class="button" href="#">Download</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```